# How to properly initialize database connection in Phalcon

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phalcon

at the moment, I initialize database in following way:

```
$di->set('db', function() use ($config){
    return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(
        array(
            "host" => $config->database->host,
            "username" => $config->database->username,
            "password" => $config->database->password,
            "dbname" => $config->database->name
        )
    );
});
```

but when mysql credentials are wrong, or database doesn't exist, Phalcon returns blank page without any error message. Such situations are real headache, because small error in login/password/host causes almost untraceable error.

I think that Pdo constructor stops PHP code execution in this case.

So how do you initialize database connection in Phalcon when you want website to tell you about problem with database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended with following code:

```
$di->set('db', function() use ($config){
    try {
        $db = new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(
            array(
                "host" => $config->database->host,
                "username" => $config->database->username,
                "password" => $config->database->password,
                "dbname" => $config->database->name
            )
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die("<b>Error when initializing database connection:</b> " . $e->getMessage());
    }
    return $db;
});
```

Please tell me if there is a better way.

Comment: Well maybe logger (like monolog) instead "die" will be better?

Comment: yes, maybe. But without db connection the application is useless, so this is ok for me.

Answer (score 3):

I use this configuration:

```
$di->set('db', function () use ($config) {
        $connection = new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
            "host" => $config->database->host,
            "username" => $config->database->username,
            "password" => $config->database->password,
            "dbname" => $config->database->dbname,
            "options" => array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
            )
        ));
        if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development') {
            $eventsManager = new Phalcon\Events\Manager();
            $logger = new Phalcon\Logger\Adapter\File($config->application->logsDir . "sql_debug.log");
            //Listen all the database events
            $eventsManager->attach('db', function ($event, $connection) use ($logger) {
                if ($event->getType() == 'beforeQuery') {
                    $logger->log($connection->getSQLStatement(), Logger::INFO);
                }
            });
            //Assign the eventsManager to the db adapter instance
            $connection->setEventsManager($eventsManager);
        }
        return $connection;
    }, true);
```

there is one more option for utf8 and if application enviroment is development, it logs all the sql calls to sql_debug.log. You can see, that I'm using $config, its defined like this:

```
switch (APPLICATION_ENV) {
        case 'development':
            $config = new Phalcon\Config\Adapter\Ini(__DIR__ . '/../app/config/config_dev.ini');
            break;
        case 'testing':
            $config = new Phalcon\Config\Adapter\Ini(__DIR__ . '/../app/config/config_test.ini');
            break;
        case 'production':
            $config = new Phalcon\Config\Adapter\Ini(__DIR__ . '/../app/config/config_production.ini');
            break;
    }
```

and in config file you would find something like this:

```
[database]
adapter = Mysql
host = localhost
username = root
password =
dbname = db_name
```

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that if you have, for example, wrong login, there would be uncaught exception on line 2 of your example and you'd probably end up with a blank page just like me.

Comment: Could you show us the file where you start to 'handle' the application? Usually the index.php file. I wrap that 'handle' in a try/catch block. I try/catch an exception, but you can do multiple catches, so try/catch pdo exception catch exception. Now you don't have your blank page anymore. Then try/catch exception in your 'db' closure to be sure

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/hp8bBznV I'm catching just all errors. You can see it from error's trace if it was db or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it more general. Sou you can catch all the errors that may occur and display them nicely.
I'm using below bootstrap file (config) for developement as [described here](http://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/debug.html#debug-component).

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);

$debug = new Phalcon\Debug();
$debug->listen();

/** Read the configuration */
$config = include __DIR__ . '/../config/config.php';

/** Read auto-loader */
include __DIR__ . "/../app/config/loader.php";

/** Read services */
include __DIR__ . "/../app/config/mvc/services.dev.php";

/** Handle the request */
$application = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application();
$application->setDI($di);
if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    $uriParts = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $uri = $uriParts[0];
} else {
    $uri = '/';
}
echo $application->handle($uri)->getContent();
```

Which concludes that interesting part is here:

```
$debug = new Phalcon\Debug();
$debug->listen();
```

Comment: nope, that doesn't change anything. I still see just a blank page when sql credentials are incorrect. Or am I missing something? Where those debug messages are supposed to go to anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Does setting error reporting in your phalcon.ini help?

```
extension=phalcon.so
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
display_errors = On
```